Connect to both Ethernet and WiFi at the same time without DHCP
I have a local server which connects to two routers via ethernet (ip a 192.x.x.x) and wifi (ip a 10.x.x.x). The ethernet router (connected to the internet) only provides internet to the server and not to any other hosts/devices. The WiFi (intranet only) can be accessed by clients and is used to connect other devices to the server. These devices connect locally to the server.
So it basically looks like this: ETHERNET ROUTER (INTERNET) only connects to--> SERVER which connects to--> WIFI ROUTER (INTRANET) which connects to--> END DEVICES
This works perfectly when the server receives its ip address via DHCP from both routers but when I set a static ip address for the WiFi intranet, the end devices can no longer access the server using this static ip address.
If I disconnect the ethernet router, then the static ip address works and devices can connect to the server. If i use DHCP instead of a static ip address, then both work. The server gets internet and devices can access the server, albeit not through a static ip address. Is there a way for me to get both to work while using a static ip address?

Sounds like a routing problem, but you haven't given enough detail (especially output if ip route) to diagnose that.   Also, you can tell the dhcp server to give out a static ip address and have it both ways.
